# LiveScript equivalent to fat arrow syntax in CoffeeScript or ES6

Tags: livescript

The `=>` in CoffeeScript or ES6 is often useful for binding `this` to a function, especially in callbacks. I can't seem to find an alternative in LiveScript. Does it exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `~>`.

Answer courtesy of `_rgn` on the `#livescript` channel on freenode.

Comment: This lets you have binded backcalls <~ which would be impossible with the <= notation.

Comment: ^ Too bad no one told TC39. :-/